# Kivy Language Indentation Rules

Tags: python-3.x, kivy-language

I'm trying to get my head around one of the kivy-examples, the showcase one.

I have a basic understandig of the Kivy language rules but I don't know how to explain this kind of indentation:

```
<ShowcaseScreen>:
    ScrollView:
        AnchorLayout:
            GridLayout:
BoxLayout:
    ActionBar:
    ScrollView:
    ScreenManager:
```

To be more specific, why the ShowcaseScreen class starts with an indented ScrollView widget and then the BoxLayout is not indented?
Based on what I see, the BoxLayout is on top of the ScrollView widget, which is somehow unexpected since the BoxLayout is the root widget...can someone clarify?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here
https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html#rule-context

`BoxLayout` is the root widget, whereas `ShowcaseScreen` is a class rule due to `<>`. They are not linked to each other, but you could put `ShowcaseScreen` below `ScreenManager` again indented.

Comment: Thanks PalimPalim but I was actually looking for the link between BoxLyout and ScrollView. Why is ScrollView indented?

Comment: everything after boxlayout must be indented. It can either be a child widget such as all the following lines in your example or a property. Boxlayout can have multiple child widgets.

Comment: I mean the ScrollView before the BoxLayout not the ScrollView within the BoxLayout. Sorry for the confusion...I know that everything after boxlayout must be intended, I can't explain what's going on before it...

Comment: that's just widgets and child widgets as part of a class rule. Indentation means child of one less indented.